# Display base64 image from database

Tags: php, base64

Is there something wrong with my code? I am asking because I failed to display the image in my browser. I have tried to decode the base64 image into png but I'm still not able to display the image. My URL format as below:
data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0kGgoAAAANSUhgAAAeAA...

My php code

---

```
    //Connect to database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("studioassessor_01") or die (mysql_error());

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM frame";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result == FALSE){
       die(mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        header("Content-type: image/png");
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_decode($row['url']) . '" />';

   }
```

After I have test for many rounds, I found that there is something wrong to my request header part in ajax scripting. The request header had changed my base 64 string value to another value.

```
            function saveIt(){

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert("Save successfully!");
                    }
                }

                var value1 = document.getElementById("url").value ;
                var value2 = document.getElementById("time").value;
                var value3 = document.getElementById("note").value;

                xmlhttp.open("POST", "insertFrame.php", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type:image/png","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send("url="+ value1 + "&time=" + value2 + "&note=" + value3);

            }
```

So, may I ask again what should i do for the xmlhttp.setRequestHeaderPart?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're decoding the base64 data into raw binary, but telling the browser that it's still base64. That's not going to work.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $row['url'] . '" />';
```

should be all you need. no decode call at all. Note that you couldn't really dump the raw binary into a data uri, even if you wanted to - it will randomly (and naturally) contain `"` and other html meta-characters, introducing html injection problems. you'd have to `htmlspecialchars()` the binary string, and then figure out if there's an encoding type `raw-binary-with-html-characters-escaped`

Comment: Hi, i have tried to use your method but still unable to display the image. Is it something wrong with my data uri? Thank you.

Comment: well, does the `url` you're fetching contain actual base64 encoded/png data, or is it literally just a url, e.g. `http://example.com/kittens.jpg`?

Comment: I have store this in my database table data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0kGgoAAAANSUhgAAAeAA... then I try to retrieve it to display as image. I am able to retrieve it but unable to display it as image

Comment: then just `<img src="' . $row['url'] . '">'` if your db already contains the entire data uri prefix. you're generating html, which means you need to look at it from the browser's point of view...

Comment: Previously, I am able to show the image using your way but now I am not able to show the image is it something wrong to my browser?

Comment: well, do a view-source on your generated page, and see what's in the `<img>` tag. if it doesn't look like what's in your db, then something in your code is causing the output to get corrupted.

Comment: Hi, I have testing for a few rounds. I found that my ajax scripting xmlHttp.setRequestHeader had change the url to some other url value. Is there any solution for this? I have try to use the $_GET before but due to the string limit not able to do so. I have updated the code above. Thank you.