# How to show a picture in Google Spreadsheets instead of its data in base64 passed by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, google-sheets, base64

My problem is that I see in the cell the result of doing .toDataURL() in Javascript to a canvas, which is fine because if I set that as the src of an img tag, the image is perfectly loaded. But I want to send it to a sheet in Google Spreadsheets along other data via form.

At the moment, when I submit the form, the sheet receives all the data, even the data of the canvas, but it's in base64, so it just shows a string, is there a way to show an actual image?

I tried sending an image instead of the dataURI but then the cell says: "[object HTMLImageElement]"

Since I'm using a library called SignaturePad for Javascript, It has an option called onEnd which allows me to add code when you stop drawing in the canvas, in that moment I pass the canvas.toDataURL() to an input hidden type.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL()
document.getElementById("signature").value = canvas.toDataURL();
```

By the way, I'm not using a database. So this question is different from [Display base64 image from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445248/display-base64-image-from-database).

Comment: It tells you how to render a base64 image, it doesn't matter the source. It is one of many duplicates which will tell you how to do this.

Comment: But does it work with Google spreadsheets?

Comment: I haven't personally tested it, but I am sure you can Google for a more exact answer.

Comment: That's the thing, I've been Googling since 10am. Now it's 6pm and I haven't found any solution to this. That's why I went to ask here.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75470/how-to-insert-a-dataimage-pngbase64-image-into-google-docs

Comment: Could you please remove the duplicated thing of my question title at least? It's not duplicated, it's something completely different. I know how to show the image via PHP, but I'm not using PHP, I just messed up and I put the tag in the question.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but because you changed tags I could only vote and not actually reopen.

Comment: Yes, I saw that page already. I have seen all the pages in the first 2 pages of results of Google search

Comment: Anyone has a solution to this?